Open Telemetry [receivers/filelog] - Append Headerdata/Metadata for Batchprocess
currently i am facing an issue splitting my batches fetched from filelogreader by "filename"
My assumption was that creating header in filelogreader receiver results in that, unforuntately i struggle with it.
Does anyone faced same issue in the past?
receivers:
  filelog:
    ...
    ...
    header:
      # Pattern machtes only values of "attributes" in event
      pattern: '"resource":{.+?}'
      metadata_operators:
        - type: regex_parser
          regex: '"filename":"(?P<filename>.+?)"'

batch/lta:
    send_batch_size: 1000
    timeout: 10s
    metadata_keys:
      - filename


Try extracting the metadata attribute from the file name. Then refer to it as attributes.filename in the batch processor config.
  receivers:
      filelog:
        ...
        include_file_name: true
        operators:
          # Extract metadata from file name
          - type: regex_parser
            id: extract_metadata_from_filename
            regex: '(?<filename>.+)'
            parse_from: attributes["log.file.name"]

